# Multithreaded AES ECB encryption

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, aes

I have been trying to make the ECB parts (at least for now) multithreaded. In the case of CBC and CFB, I don't think it is possible and I might be wrong. I found this code here https://github.com/SergeyBel/AES

```
#include "AES.h"

AES::AES(const AESKeyLength keyLength) {
  switch (keyLength) {
    case AESKeyLength::AES_128:
      this->Nk = 4;
      this->Nr = 10;
      break;
    case AESKeyLength::AES_192:
      this->Nk = 6;
      this->Nr = 12;
      break;
    case AESKeyLength::AES_256:
      this->Nk = 8;
      this->Nr = 14;
      break;
  }
}

unsigned char *AES::EncryptECB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[]) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    EncryptBlock(in + i, out + i, roundKeys);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::DecryptECB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[]) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    DecryptBlock(in + i, out + i, roundKeys);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::EncryptCBC(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    XorBlocks(block, in + i, block, blockBytesLen);
    EncryptBlock(block, out + i, roundKeys);
    memcpy(block, out + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::DecryptCBC(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    DecryptBlock(in + i, out + i, roundKeys);
    XorBlocks(block, out + i, out + i, blockBytesLen);
    memcpy(block, in + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::EncryptCFB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char encryptedBlock[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    EncryptBlock(block, encryptedBlock, roundKeys);
    XorBlocks(in + i, encryptedBlock, out + i, blockBytesLen);
    memcpy(block, out + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::DecryptCFB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char encryptedBlock[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    EncryptBlock(block, encryptedBlock, roundKeys);
    XorBlocks(in + i, encryptedBlock, out + i, blockBytesLen);
    memcpy(block, in + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

void AES::CheckLength(unsigned int len) {
  if (len % blockBytesLen != 0) {
    throw std::length_error("Plaintext length must be divisible by " +
                            std::to_string(blockBytesLen));
  }
}

void AES::EncryptBlock(const unsigned char in[], unsigned char out[],
                       unsigned char *roundKeys) {
  unsigned char state[4][Nb];
  unsigned int i, j, round;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      state[i][j] = in[i + 4 * j];
    }
  }

  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys);

  for (round = 1; round <= Nr - 1; round++) {
    SubBytes(state);
    ShiftRows(state);
    MixColumns(state);
    AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + round * 4 * Nb);
  }

  SubBytes(state);
  ShiftRows(state);
  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + Nr * 4 * Nb);

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      out[i + 4 * j] = state[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void AES::DecryptBlock(const unsigned char in[], unsigned char out[],
                       unsigned char *roundKeys) {
  unsigned char state[4][Nb];
  unsigned int i, j, round;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      state[i][j] = in[i + 4 * j];
    }
  }

  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + Nr * 4 * Nb);

  for (round = Nr - 1; round >= 1; round--) {
    InvSubBytes(state);
    InvShiftRows(state);
    AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + round * 4 * Nb);
    InvMixColumns(state);
  }

  InvSubBytes(state);
  InvShiftRows(state);
  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys);

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      out[i + 4 * j] = state[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void AES::SubBytes(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  unsigned char t;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      t = state[i][j];
      state[i][j] = sbox[t / 16][t % 16];
    }
  }
}

void AES::ShiftRow(unsigned char state[4][Nb], unsigned int i,
                   unsigned int n)  // shift row i on n positions
{
  unsigned char tmp[Nb];
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
    tmp[j] = state[i][(j + n) % Nb];
  }
  memcpy(state[i], tmp, Nb * sizeof(unsigned char));
}

void AES::ShiftRows(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  ShiftRow(state, 1, 1);
  ShiftRow(state, 2, 2);
  ShiftRow(state, 3, 3);
}

unsigned char AES::xtime(unsigned char b)  // multiply on x
{
  return (b << 1) ^ (((b >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b);
}

void AES::MixColumns(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned char temp_state[4][Nb];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memset(temp_state[i], 0, 4);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        if (CMDS[i][k] == 1)
          temp_state[i][j] ^= state[k][j];
        else
          temp_state[i][j] ^= GF_MUL_TABLE[CMDS[i][k]][state[k][j]];
      }
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memcpy(state[i], temp_state[i], 4);
  }
}

void AES::AddRoundKey(unsigned char state[4][Nb], unsigned char *key) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      state[i][j] = state[i][j] ^ key[i + 4 * j];
    }
  }
}

void AES::SubWord(unsigned char *a) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    a[i] = sbox[a[i] / 16][a[i] % 16];
  }
}

void AES::RotWord(unsigned char *a) {
  unsigned char c = a[0];
  a[0] = a[1];
  a[1] = a[2];
  a[2] = a[3];
  a[3] = c;
}

void AES::XorWords(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b, unsigned char *c) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
  }
}

void AES::Rcon(unsigned char *a, unsigned int n) {
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned char c = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    c = xtime(c);
  }

  a[0] = c;
  a[1] = a[2] = a[3] = 0;
}

void AES::KeyExpansion(const unsigned char key[], unsigned char w[]) {
  unsigned char temp[4];
  unsigned char rcon[4];

  unsigned int i = 0;
  while (i < 4 * Nk) {
    w[i] = key[i];
    i++;
  }

  i = 4 * Nk;
  while (i < 4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)) {
    temp[0] = w[i - 4 + 0];
    temp[1] = w[i - 4 + 1];
    temp[2] = w[i - 4 + 2];
    temp[3] = w[i - 4 + 3];

    if (i / 4 % Nk == 0) {
      RotWord(temp);
      SubWord(temp);
      Rcon(rcon, i / (Nk * 4));
      XorWords(temp, rcon, temp);
    } else if (Nk > 6 && i / 4 % Nk == 4) {
      SubWord(temp);
    }

    w[i + 0] = w[i - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[0];
    w[i + 1] = w[i + 1 - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[1];
    w[i + 2] = w[i + 2 - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[2];
    w[i + 3] = w[i + 3 - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[3];
    i += 4;
  }
}

void AES::InvSubBytes(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  unsigned char t;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      t = state[i][j];
      state[i][j] = inv_sbox[t / 16][t % 16];
    }
  }
}

void AES::InvMixColumns(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned char temp_state[4][Nb];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memset(temp_state[i], 0, 4);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        temp_state[i][j] ^= GF_MUL_TABLE[INV_CMDS[i][k]][state[k][j]];
      }
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memcpy(state[i], temp_state[i], 4);
  }
}

void AES::InvShiftRows(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  ShiftRow(state, 1, Nb - 1);
  ShiftRow(state, 2, Nb - 2);
  ShiftRow(state, 3, Nb - 3);
}

void AES::XorBlocks(const unsigned char *a, const unsigned char *b,
                    unsigned char *c, unsigned int len) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
  }
}

void AES::printHexArray(unsigned char a[], unsigned int n) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", a[i]);
  }
}

void AES::printHexVector(std::vector<unsigned char> a) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", a[i]);
  }
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::ArrayToVector(unsigned char *a,
                                              unsigned int len) {
  std::vector<unsigned char> v(a, a + len * sizeof(unsigned char));
  return v;
}

unsigned char *AES::VectorToArray(std::vector<unsigned char> &a) {
  return a.data();
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::EncryptECB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key) {
  unsigned char *out = EncryptECB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::DecryptECB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key) {
  unsigned char *out = DecryptECB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, (unsigned int)in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::EncryptCBC(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = EncryptCBC(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::DecryptCBC(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = DecryptCBC(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, (unsigned int)in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::EncryptCFB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = EncryptCFB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::DecryptCFB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = DecryptCFB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, (unsigned int)in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}
```

Can someone please guide me and maybe show how to do it?

I have tried to synchronize threads but the execution time is taking way longer. This is the one I am trying to optimize

```
#include <thread>

#include "AES.h"

AES::AES(const AESKeyLength keyLength) {
  switch (keyLength) {
    case AESKeyLength::AES_128:
      this->Nk = 4;
      this->Nr = 10;
      break;
    case AESKeyLength::AES_192:
      this->Nk = 6;
      this->Nr = 12;
      break;
    case AESKeyLength::AES_256:
      this->Nk = 8;
      this->Nr = 14;
      break;
  }
}

unsigned char *AES::EncryptECB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[]) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);

  // Calculate number of threads
  unsigned int numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  // Calculate the size of each chunk
  unsigned int chunkSize = inLen / numThreads;

  // Start all threads
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(numThreads);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    unsigned int start = i * chunkSize;
    unsigned int size = (i == numThreads - 1)
                            ? (inLen - start)
                            : chunkSize;  // Handle the last chunk

    threads[i] = std::thread([this, roundKeys, in, out, start, size]() {
      for (unsigned int j = start; j < start + size; j += blockBytesLen) {
        EncryptBlock(in + j, out + j, roundKeys);
      }
    });
  }

  // Wait for all threads to finish
  for (std::thread &t : threads) {
    if (t.joinable()) {
      t.join();
    }
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;
  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::DecryptECB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[]) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);

  // Calculate number of threads
  unsigned int numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  // Calculate the size of each chunk
  unsigned int chunkSize = inLen / numThreads;

  // Start all threads
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(numThreads);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    unsigned int start = i * chunkSize;
    unsigned int size = (i == numThreads - 1)
                            ? (inLen - start)
                            : chunkSize;  // Handle the last chunk

    threads[i] = std::thread([this, roundKeys, in, out, start, size]() {
      for (unsigned int j = start; j < start + size; j += blockBytesLen) {
        DecryptBlock(in + j, out + j, roundKeys);
      }
    });
  }

  // Wait for all threads to finish
  for (std::thread &t : threads) {
    if (t.joinable()) {
      t.join();
    }
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;
  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::EncryptCBC(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    XorBlocks(block, in + i, block, blockBytesLen);
    EncryptBlock(block, out + i, roundKeys);
    memcpy(block, out + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::DecryptCBC(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    DecryptBlock(in + i, out + i, roundKeys);
    XorBlocks(block, out + i, out + i, blockBytesLen);
    memcpy(block, in + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::EncryptCFB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char encryptedBlock[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    EncryptBlock(block, encryptedBlock, roundKeys);
    XorBlocks(in + i, encryptedBlock, out + i, blockBytesLen);
    memcpy(block, out + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

unsigned char *AES::DecryptCFB(const unsigned char in[], unsigned int inLen,
                               const unsigned char key[],
                               const unsigned char *iv) {
  CheckLength(inLen);
  unsigned char *out = new unsigned char[inLen];
  unsigned char block[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char encryptedBlock[blockBytesLen];
  unsigned char *roundKeys = new unsigned char[4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)];
  KeyExpansion(key, roundKeys);
  memcpy(block, iv, blockBytesLen);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inLen; i += blockBytesLen) {
    EncryptBlock(block, encryptedBlock, roundKeys);
    XorBlocks(in + i, encryptedBlock, out + i, blockBytesLen);
    memcpy(block, in + i, blockBytesLen);
  }

  delete[] roundKeys;

  return out;
}

void AES::CheckLength(unsigned int len) {
  if (len % blockBytesLen != 0) {
    throw std::length_error("Plaintext length must be divisible by " +
                            std::to_string(blockBytesLen));
  }
}

void AES::EncryptBlock(const unsigned char in[], unsigned char out[],
                       unsigned char *roundKeys) {
  unsigned char state[4][Nb];
  unsigned int i, j, round;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      state[i][j] = in[i + 4 * j];
    }
  }

  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys);

  for (round = 1; round <= Nr - 1; round++) {
    SubBytes(state);
    ShiftRows(state);
    MixColumns(state);
    AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + round * 4 * Nb);
  }

  SubBytes(state);
  ShiftRows(state);
  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + Nr * 4 * Nb);

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      out[i + 4 * j] = state[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void AES::DecryptBlock(const unsigned char in[], unsigned char out[],
                       unsigned char *roundKeys) {
  unsigned char state[4][Nb];
  unsigned int i, j, round;

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      state[i][j] = in[i + 4 * j];
    }
  }

  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + Nr * 4 * Nb);

  for (round = Nr - 1; round >= 1; round--) {
    InvSubBytes(state);
    InvShiftRows(state);
    AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys + round * 4 * Nb);
    InvMixColumns(state);
  }

  InvSubBytes(state);
  InvShiftRows(state);
  AddRoundKey(state, roundKeys);

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      out[i + 4 * j] = state[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void AES::SubBytes(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  unsigned char t;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      t = state[i][j];
      state[i][j] = sbox[t / 16][t % 16];
    }
  }
}

void AES::ShiftRow(unsigned char state[4][Nb], unsigned int i,
                   unsigned int n)  // shift row i on n positions
{
  unsigned char tmp[Nb];
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
    tmp[j] = state[i][(j + n) % Nb];
  }
  memcpy(state[i], tmp, Nb * sizeof(unsigned char));
}

void AES::ShiftRows(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  ShiftRow(state, 1, 1);
  ShiftRow(state, 2, 2);
  ShiftRow(state, 3, 3);
}

unsigned char AES::xtime(unsigned char b)  // multiply on x
{
  return (b << 1) ^ (((b >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b);
}

void AES::MixColumns(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned char temp_state[4][Nb];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memset(temp_state[i], 0, 4);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        if (CMDS[i][k] == 1)
          temp_state[i][j] ^= state[k][j];
        else
          temp_state[i][j] ^= GF_MUL_TABLE[CMDS[i][k]][state[k][j]];
      }
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memcpy(state[i], temp_state[i], 4);
  }
}

void AES::AddRoundKey(unsigned char state[4][Nb], unsigned char *key) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      state[i][j] = state[i][j] ^ key[i + 4 * j];
    }
  }
}

void AES::SubWord(unsigned char *a) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    a[i] = sbox[a[i] / 16][a[i] % 16];
  }
}

void AES::RotWord(unsigned char *a) {
  unsigned char c = a[0];
  a[0] = a[1];
  a[1] = a[2];
  a[2] = a[3];
  a[3] = c;
}

void AES::XorWords(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b, unsigned char *c) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
  }
}

void AES::Rcon(unsigned char *a, unsigned int n) {
  unsigned int i;
  unsigned char c = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    c = xtime(c);
  }

  a[0] = c;
  a[1] = a[2] = a[3] = 0;
}

void AES::KeyExpansion(const unsigned char key[], unsigned char w[]) {
  unsigned char temp[4];
  unsigned char rcon[4];

  unsigned int i = 0;
  while (i < 4 * Nk) {
    w[i] = key[i];
    i++;
  }

  i = 4 * Nk;
  while (i < 4 * Nb * (Nr + 1)) {
    temp[0] = w[i - 4 + 0];
    temp[1] = w[i - 4 + 1];
    temp[2] = w[i - 4 + 2];
    temp[3] = w[i - 4 + 3];

    if (i / 4 % Nk == 0) {
      RotWord(temp);
      SubWord(temp);
      Rcon(rcon, i / (Nk * 4));
      XorWords(temp, rcon, temp);
    } else if (Nk > 6 && i / 4 % Nk == 4) {
      SubWord(temp);
    }

    w[i + 0] = w[i - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[0];
    w[i + 1] = w[i + 1 - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[1];
    w[i + 2] = w[i + 2 - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[2];
    w[i + 3] = w[i + 3 - 4 * Nk] ^ temp[3];
    i += 4;
  }
}

void AES::InvSubBytes(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned int i, j;
  unsigned char t;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Nb; j++) {
      t = state[i][j];
      state[i][j] = inv_sbox[t / 16][t % 16];
    }
  }
}

void AES::InvMixColumns(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  unsigned char temp_state[4][Nb];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memset(temp_state[i], 0, 4);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        temp_state[i][j] ^= GF_MUL_TABLE[INV_CMDS[i][k]][state[k][j]];
      }
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    memcpy(state[i], temp_state[i], 4);
  }
}

void AES::InvShiftRows(unsigned char state[4][Nb]) {
  ShiftRow(state, 1, Nb - 1);
  ShiftRow(state, 2, Nb - 2);
  ShiftRow(state, 3, Nb - 3);
}

void AES::XorBlocks(const unsigned char *a, const unsigned char *b,
                    unsigned char *c, unsigned int len) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
  }
}

void AES::printHexArray(unsigned char a[], unsigned int n) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", a[i]);
  }
}

void AES::printHexVector(std::vector<unsigned char> a) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", a[i]);
  }
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::ArrayToVector(unsigned char *a,
                                              unsigned int len) {
  std::vector<unsigned char> v(a, a + len * sizeof(unsigned char));
  return v;
}

unsigned char *AES::VectorToArray(std::vector<unsigned char> &a) {
  return a.data();
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::EncryptECB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key) {
  unsigned char *out = EncryptECB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::DecryptECB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key) {
  unsigned char *out = DecryptECB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, (unsigned int)in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::EncryptCBC(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = EncryptCBC(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::DecryptCBC(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = DecryptCBC(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, (unsigned int)in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::EncryptCFB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = EncryptCFB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> AES::DecryptCFB(std::vector<unsigned char> in,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> key,
                                           std::vector<unsigned char> iv) {
  unsigned char *out = DecryptCFB(VectorToArray(in), (unsigned int)in.size(),
                                  VectorToArray(key), VectorToArray(iv));
  std::vector<unsigned char> v = ArrayToVector(out, (unsigned int)in.size());
  delete[] out;
  return v;
}
```

you would execute by g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread ../src/AES.cpp 256ECB.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ECB mode has very few secure use-case scenarios, so I don't really think it's worth the effort to do any optimization there. Your best bet if you want to parallelize is to use CTR mode or maybe GCM. Also CBC and CFB are possible in decryption.

Then, as you noted, you actually get worse performance. My guess is that the overhead of starting the threads is not offset by the gain because the data set is too small. There's significant overhead starting a new thread, so you need to process quite a bit of data before you get ahead of the curve so to speak. This is why for example long running multi threaded processes like web servers have thread pools, where threads can be re-used at a lower initial cost than creating new ones.

Finally, for optimization, it's probably better to use an existing library implementation that hopefully already is optimized in it's computations and will be using underlying CPU instruction set optimization or even AES-specific hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. I am actually measuring hardware counters using perf to know how well it runs a rbpi 4. Any ideas on optimized libraries? That would be great

Comment: It depends on the hardware... Nvidia GPU's can be extremely fast for this. The choice of optimization also depends a bit on the application - large amounts with the same key, or small amounts with different keys, because the AES key setup is also pretty expensive. openssl should be fairly good on all platforms. Crypto API on Windows should also perform well there. Wikipedia actually has a pretty good list to start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations .